# How to open aMSN that has been minimised to the tray?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I have problems maximizing apps like aMSN which closes into tray when I press the close (x) button. In a usual Gnome I would call it from the tray, but Gnome3 does not have it.

So, how should I maximize (bring to front) apps in Gnome3 that can be restored only via clicking on its tray icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any (well almost any) application that in previous versions minimised to the system tray notification area will still appear in the system-tray area of Gnome-Shell.  The location though is not immediately obvious - it is in the bottom-right of the screen.

[image]

Move your mouse to the bottom-right to reveal this area - its an auto-hidden like panel.  Just click on any of the apps in the system-tray to make them reappear.

As you have pointed out aMsn when minimised seemingly disappears - this happens in both Gnome-Shell and Unity.

To stop this magical disappearing trick you can edit the file `/home/your_username/.amsn/[your_email]/config.xml`, search for `use_tray` and change the value from `1` to `0`

This still doesnt allow aMsn to minimise to the correct area in the shell - but aMsn does appear as an open window when you click the Activities menu.

Note in Unity - this trick allows aMsn to remain as an icon in the Launcher.

---

If you are not adverse to installing PPAs, then instead of the above you could install the classic-systray extension

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-classic-systray
```

Logout and login and enable the classic-tray extension in gnome-tweak-tool.

Logout and login again.  This time, aMsn when it minimises, appears in the top-bar as shown.

Comment: Could you please try this with aMSN. It works with Skype, but aMSN does not work this way. If I close it, I can find it nowhere, but if I start another amsn via console, it says that another aMSN service is running (!). If I try to minimize aMSN (click on close x button then Minimize To Try, it does not minimize to right bottom, but it gets stuck in the left side of screen, just below the Activities word.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, worked for me

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html

Comment: While this may technically be a an answer. Please don't just post a link. Summarise the key steps.