# "Can not setup lock file:/tmp/g2ipmsg.lock errno : -11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)"

Tags: networking

I installed IP Messenger (GNOME 2) from Ubuntu software center but its not working. It's always showing an error message on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
FileName:ipmsg.c
Function:create_lock_file
Line:157
Can not setup lock file:/tmp/g2ipmsg.lock errno : -11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Comment: To add to it, if anyone sends a message, g2ipmessenger crashes

Comment: @Madhu K. Did you got any solution for this problem so far? As i am having the same issue with Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: did you try this http://askubuntu.com/a/321085/202806

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @mohit_rocks That answer had an obvious typo/error in it. But I guess you all noticed the missing `rm`. (If not, then try that again.)

Comment: did you mean **sudo rm /tmp/g2ipmsg.lock** ?

Comment: @mohit_rocks Yes.

Comment: it still doesn't work..

Comment: Does `/tmp` exist? And does the directory and the user have the proper permissions? `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` and `sudo chown root.root /tmp` Did you use `sudo` when trying to install?

Comment: I've just [solved](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632626/ip-messenger-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/633274#633274) it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first about /tmp/ directory and that it is writeable by all users.

Also try this solution :

1. Type on terminal below command - `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`
2. Restart and click gnome ip messenger still it may give create lock file error but it will be viewable in notification panel.
3. If still this doesn't work make sure that you can write to /tmp, try `touch /tmp/foo` to make sure you can write in it
4. Next, see whether there is a lock file in /tmp: ls -l /tmp/g2ipmsg.lock if you can't see try with `sudo ls -a /tmp/`
5. You can see know who owns the lock file. If there is a lock file, check whether the process is running with pgrep ipmsg.  If not, remove it: `rm /tmp/g2ipmsg.lock` or `sudo rm /tmp/g2ipmsg.lock`

Let us know if it worked

Comment: `"No such schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel'"` error

Comment: Hi Parth, for this error you should check this article : http://askubuntu.com/questions/362135/how-to-re-enable-tray-icons-for-applications-in-ubuntu-13-10  Let me know if you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem. Here you can try alternative [Iptux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/iptux/). You can send/receive message to/from ipmsg on windows and iptux on Ubuntu.

To install iptux use command :

```
sudo apt-get install iptux
```

Comment: but it cannot receive msgs from windows systems... i am using it.. its not good