# How to fix missing panel indicators in 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, panel

After moving from 12.04 to 13.10 (with unity), the majority of my applications no longer have panel indicators.
e.g:
- xchat
- sonata

xchat gets a link in the mail menu, but this is useless because it opens a new xchat instance each time it's clicked, rather than bringing up the existing one.

I understand that this is a change from 13.04 to 'tidy up' the notification area, but it's super frustrating. Is there any way to force the old behaviour so that all of my applications can have status indicators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a ppa which brings back the old whitelist functionality. See here: [How to re-enable tray icons for applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362135/how-to-re-enable-tray-icons-for-applications-in-ubuntu-13-10)