# How to reinstall Unity?

Tags: unity, 13.10

A few months ago I installed [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/systray-white) from the recommendation of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368549/129009). It now turns out that it's buggy as hell and breaks nearly everything almost all the time.

I tried removing the ppa and reinstalling unity, but I get the message
`Reinstallation of unity is not possible, it cannot be downloaded`.

How do I go back to using unaltered Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already removed the ppa, you have to add it again for this to work:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mc3man/systray-white
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, purge the ppa, which will remove it from your sources and restore the packages to the official version:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/systray-white
```

In case ppa-purge is not installed, do:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Comment: @Jobin Agreed, although purging the ppa should automatically reinstall the package.

Comment: `Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: mc3man systray-white`

Comment: I reinstalled the ppa and then purged it, that worked. Thank you, this has been bugging me for months.