# Skype icon doesn't show up on app indicator on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: indicator, 16.04, skype, menu-bar

When I log in to Skype, the Skype icon doesn't show up on the app indicator (tray/menu bar right side) on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

I've tried the installing the `libappindicator1` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/370654/119592), and it worked for Slack, but not for Skype.
I've also tried intalling `sni-qt`, but it was already installed: `sni-qt is already the newest version (0.2.7+15.10.20150729-0ubuntu1).`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Install the **sni-qt** package.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it's already installed :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Be sure to have sni-qt installed for i386 :

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```

Answer (score 15):

For me on Ubuntu 16.10 installing `libappindicator1` and restarting skype solved the problem

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Comment: Same applies to Skype for linux beta version on fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 , installing libappindicator1 and rebooting machine brings the icon back on the tray. thx @Leszek

Comment: Perfect solution. I am using 16.04 LTS, latest version at 2015 May and the problem still there.

Comment: This solution works also for `Skype version 8.18.0.6` | `Calling version 2018.11.01.10`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Note that solutions mentioned here do not work with Ubuntu 17.04 due to a different reason mentioned here:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9046
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1629251

Also note that `sni-qt:i386` package and all qt i386 dependencies are not required for "amd64" version of `skypeforlinux`. Instead you can use following workaround mentioned in the Unity bug:

```
$ env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity skypeforlinux
```

This will launch `skypeforlinux` with environment variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` set to `Unity`, the default value of this variable in Ubuntu 17.04 is `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity:Unity7` that confuses the electron (which Skype for Linux is build upon).

You can also use this line in the Startup Application entry, but then you should disable "Launch at Login" in Skype and create your own entry.